# QGIS Field Calculator provides incorrect answer when using the Maximum function

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I'm using:

- The field calculator in QGIS

I'm trying to:

- Find the winner of each election

Problems:

- When there there is NO WINNER in an election, the field calculator incorrectly picks the candidate in the column furthest to the left as the winner.
- When there is A TIE in an election, the field calculator incorrectly picks the candidate in the column furthest to left as the winner.

Example:

```
+------------+----------------+------------+---------------+----------+
|  District  | Terry Tortoise | Harry Hare | Chuck Cheetah |  Winner  |
+------------+----------------+------------+---------------+----------+
| District 1 |              1 |          0 |             0 | Tortoise |
| District 2 |              0 |          1 |             0 | Hare     |
| District 3 |              0 |          0 |             1 | Cheetah  |
| District 4 |              0 |          0 |             0 | Tortoise |
| District 5 |              0 |          1 |             1 | Hare     |
+------------+----------------+------------+---------------+----------+
```

What I've been inputing in the field calculator:

```
CASE
WHEN "Tortoise" = max (Terry Tortoise, Harry Hare, Chuck Cheetah) THEN 'Tortoise'
WHEN "Hare" = max (Terry Tortoise, Harry Hare, Chuck Cheetah) THEN 'Hare'
WHEN "Cheetah" = max (Terry Tortoise, Harry Hare, Chuck Cheetah) THEN 'Cheetah'
END
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The field calculator is not incorrect, it is simply filling the field according to the conditional statements you have provided in your expression (notwithstanding the apparent syntax errors).

When all values are 0, then the `max` function returns 0 and the calculator fills the field with the value you requested when the first column e.g. `"Terry Tortoise"` matches that condition.
Similarly, when two columns fulfil the `max` condition, it will fill with the value you requested from the first column (`"Harry Hare"`) which matches that condition.
You need to tell the field calculator explicitly what to do when all columns are 0, and include an else clause which covers the possibility of more than one column containing the `max` value.
The expression below should achieve your goal.

```
CASE
WHEN "Terry Tortoise" = max("Terry Tortoise", "Harry Hare", "Chuck Cheetah") AND NOT "Harry Hare" = max("Terry Tortoise", "Harry Hare", "Chuck Cheetah") AND NOT "Chuck Cheetah" = max("Terry Tortoise", "Harry Hare", "Chuck Cheetah") THEN 'Tortoise'
WHEN "Harry Hare" = max("Terry Tortoise", "Harry Hare", "Chuck Cheetah") AND NOT "Terry Tortoise" = max("Terry Tortoise", "Harry Hare", "Chuck Cheetah") AND NOT "Chuck Cheetah" = max("Terry Tortoise", "Harry Hare", "Chuck Cheetah") THEN 'Hare'
WHEN "Chuck Cheetah" = max("Terry Tortoise", "Harry Hare", "Chuck Cheetah") AND NOT "Terry Tortoise" = max("Terry Tortoise", "Harry Hare", "Chuck Cheetah") AND NOT "Harry Hare" = max("Terry Tortoise", "Harry Hare", "Chuck Cheetah") THEN 'Cheetah'
WHEN max("Terry Tortoise", "Harry Hare", "Chuck Cheetah") = 0 THEN 'No winner'
ELSE 'Tie'
END
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! You explained it so well! I am so grateful!

Comment: I'm new to this and I guess I was having trouble with the syntax. Thank you for showing me how! :) I hope you have a wonderful day!

Comment: You are most welcome- I am very happy to have been of assistance!